# How to get google maps markers' info window working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looping through a json result set from a third party API and plotting the locations on a google map. 
I have that part working. 
The issue is when clicking on the markers the info window pops up with an x instead of displaying the location's name. Below is most of my code and here is the results from when I do console.log(locations):

```
 0: {lat: 39.3279, lng: 74.5035}
 1: {lat: 40.402387, lng: 47.210994}
 2: {lat: 48.63333, lng: 2.3}
```

I need help understanding what I am doing incorrectly. 
Thank you

```
$.ajax({
url: 'api/id',   
success: function (result) {   
  for (const row of result.payload) {
 locations.push({lat: row.latitude, lng: row.longitude});
  }
  console.log(locations);
 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    console.log(locations.length);
    marker=  new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: locations[i].lat, lng: locations[i].lng},
      map: map,
      data: {
       name: locations[i][0]
       }
    });
   marker.addListener('click', function() {
     console.log('click');
      if(!this.infoWindow) {
       this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: this.data.name            
       });
      }
      this.infoWindow.open(map,this);
    })
  };
},
 error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown);
   }
 })
 }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like at no point are you actually bringing in the name, it's not in your locations array.

Comment: I added it now, locations.push({lat: row.latitude, lng: row.longitude, name: row.chabadHouseName});    But when i do a console.log('locations ' + locations[i][0]); its logging undefined

Comment: why not use locations[i].name like you do for lat and long?

Comment: This looks like basic JavaScript debugging.  Did you know you can set a breakpoint in Chrome developer tools and inspect all your objects?

Comment: Thats logging [object Object].

Comment: What is the output when you console.log(results);?

Comment: @imvain2 your suggestion worked! thank you! its now displaying the name in the popup window. But how do I get it to display the actual address, and the rest of the info like any other legit google map?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question in the comments " its now displaying the name in the popup window. But how do I get it to display the actual address, and the rest of the info like any other legit google map? "

You need to reverse geocode this coordinates you're using in order to display the actual address. You can refer to the sample in :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

```
 function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the info window like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/id',   
    success: function (result) {   
        for (const row of result.payload) {
            locations.push({lat: row.latitude, lng: row.longitude});
        }
        console.log(locations);
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
            console.log(locations.length);
            marker=  new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: locations[i].lat, lng: locations[i].lng},
                map: map,
                data: {
                    name: locations[i][0]
                }
             });

             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: locations[i][0]
             });

             marker.addListener('click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map, marker)
             })
       };
   },
   error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(errorThrown);
   }
})
```